# Session not save after redirect in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I have created a template page in WordPress. I want save the value in the session by opening the template page link, but I do not get that value after being redirected to product page. So what am I doing wrong?

I'm trying in the code below.

This is template file where i set session!

```PHP
<?php
/**
* Template Name: HDFC Coupon
*/

$coupon_code = 'HDFC10EGMKKRYD';
$coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_code);
$product_ids = $coupon->get_product_ids();

$_SESSION['HDFC_COUPON_VALID'] = true;

if(count($product_ids) == 1){
    $url = get_permalink(reset($product_ids));
}else{
    $url = wc_get_cart_url();
}
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

This is `function.php` code where i want to get session value, but i got black array of session!

```PHP
<?php
session_start();

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'woocommerce_get_price_fun', 10, 2);
function woocommerce_get_price_fun($price, $product){

    // here it's blank when i print this : print_r($_SESSION)

    if(is_product() && isset($_SESSION['HDFC_COUPON_VALID']) && $_SESSION['HDFC_COUPON_VALID']){
        // sonthing which i want to do after session value get.
    }
    return $price;
}
```

it's working fine when i comment this line `wp_redirect($url);`, but when i use redirect then it not save data in session.

Comment: Error reporting revealed what?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i already read those question, It is not appropriate for you to close the question without understanding it. 
because my question is, it's already working if i comment redirect line. but when i use redirect then it not save data in session.

Comment: You never answered my question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner But I do not understand your question, what you asking ?

Comment: can you please clarify  your question again?

Comment: Consult the following: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and put that in all your php files.

Comment: it's already enabled, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','on');`  but it nothing display as error

Comment: I've reopened the question. Let's see if someone else can find what the cause could be.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has it's own session handler, which you can use by calling `WC()->session`. https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session_Handler.html

It's possible that this is conflicting with session writes if you're using the `$_SESSION` superglobal, particularly if you're calling `exit` before the session has been written.

Instead, try using

`WC()->session->set('HDFC_COUPON_VALID', true);`

and

`WC()->session->get('HDFC_COUPON_VALID');`

followed by

`WC()->session->save_data();`

Comment: still not working, still i can't get session value in redirected page ! it working with same page but it not save for those browser !

Comment: sorry, i missed your reply! Updated my answer - try adding `WC()->session->save_data();` before you redirect.